# I can't figure out how to set the file extension for my programming language (built in python)

Tags: python, programming-languages

So I'm building a programming language in Python, and I **can't** figure out how to set what the file extension for my language will be. Like, I can't figure out how to specify, within the code, what the file ending (s) will be for this language. The repo is [here](https://github.com/Zachinquarantine/learn2020).

Comment: File extensions are managed by and only have meaning for the OS.

Comment: You specify the file extension when you create the file in your text editor (or your file manager or shell or however you're creating the file). If you want your interpreter to only accept files with certain extensions (though why would you want that?), you can use a simple if-statement for that (something along the lines of `if not filename.endswith(".ext"): print("Wrong file extension"); sys.exit()`). That said, looking at your repo, you don't seem to be reading from a file at all, so file extensions wouldn't enter into it.